# Creating new attribute field gained by areal intersection in QGIS

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, fields-attributes, qgsexpression

I am trying to make a new attribute field which will differentiate points, vector layer, which lie inside and outside of a polygon layer.

I tried like this:

```sql
CASE
    WHEN 'points_67ebb752_4208_4b2b_9b1d_419efb341ff3' IN 'polygon_D_e5a424dd_6e6f_447e_952a_44b4f0dd6f9a' THEN 1
    ELSE 2
END
```

Would something like this possible at all in a way that a layer is used to differentiate on another layer, position vise, so that end result are two different values on an attribute field of the first layer.

Comment: `IN` is used to determine whether a value is within a list of values (which is shown in the example in the field calculator).

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
if(overlay_within('polygon_D_e5a424dd_6e6f_447e_952a_44b4f0dd6f9a'), 1, 2)
```

It utilizes the [`overlay_within()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#overlay-within) and [`if()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#if) functions.